# WordPress Theme Options insert in custom database table with $wpdb-insert

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been working out with this quite a long time and I can't find a way how to make it work.

I'm creating a simple theme option with my theme but putting all the options to a custom database table.
I want to know how $wpdb->insert() inserts all options like add_option().

This is my code - http://pastebin.com/5xHBs6r2
If you look at line 209 *function stheme_initialize_theme_options()* you'll see what I mean. I also created a function (*function stheme_default_options()*) that holds the default options and return it with **apply_filters()**.

I hope someone can help me with this as I'm really struggling with it for a week now.

Thank you!
Best regards.

Comment: have you checked the source of wpdb class, in particular `function _insert_replace_helper`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Options API.  It's a lot simpler than writing your own queries, and it's built in already.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

Setting, resetting and retrieving options you store can be done with 3 or 4 commands altogether, so it's a pretty nifty system.  For instance, this:

```
add_option('my_option', 'foo');
```

Will instantiate an option in the DB, this will update it:

```
update_option('my_option', 'foo2');
```

and finally, this will retrieve it:

```
$s = get_option('my_option');
```

If you do use the Options APi, it's a good idea to stick to a naming convention, have your own prefix for your options.  Too easy to cross over to other plugins etc if you use anything too obvious.

Comment: I know how to use Options API. I wan't my theme to have this custom table so when my theme deactivates all will be delete including all db junk left.

Comment: So you intend to write a clearup function on theme deactivate?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that, I just saw that you do.

IMO, it would be just as easy to write deactivate code to remove the options from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Don't create a table to do something that WordPress already does. You're even putting yourself into a trap, as you won't be able to query your data with WP default tools and will have to re-invent the wheel to achieve it.

What you're looking for is [`register_activation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), [`register_deactivation_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook) and [`register_uninstall_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook).

Aside the uninstall hook, we can use the file `uninstall.php` with our plugins to clean up our stuff after the plugin is deleted. See [this related posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=uninstall.php%20is:a) at WordPress Answers.

---

PS: in your code, this is totally uncalled for:

```
add_action( 'init', 'st_register_table', 1 );
```

You address custom tables simply with `$wpdb->prefix.'your_table'`.